# UWP Prevent Auto-Focus on AutosuggestBox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have an `AutosuggestBox` inside a `ContentDialog` like this:

```
<ContentDialog x:Name="BrowseBySourceDialog"                                   
            Grid.Column="1"
            PrimaryButtonText="{x:Bind ViewModel._BTN_ok}"
            PrimaryButtonClick="BrowseBySourceDialog_PrimaryButtonClick"
            SecondaryButtonClick="Dialog_SecondaryButtonClick"
            SecondaryButtonText="{x:Bind ViewModel._BTN_close}"
            Opened="BrowseBySourceDialog_Opened"
            GotFocus="BrowseBySourceDialog_GotFocus"
            Style="{StaticResource ContentDialogStyles}">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <Border Background="#1A503E"
                MinHeight="40"
                Grid.Row="0">

        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel._HEADER_BROWSE_sourceOrganization}"                     
                    Style="{StaticResource DialogTextBlockStyle}" />
    </Border>

    <ListView Name="BrowseBySourceTopResultsListView" IsTabStop="True"
                x:FieldModifier="public"
                Grid.Row="3"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                ItemClick="FeaturedResultsSourceListView_ItemClick"
                MaxHeight="500"                                                                             
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind BrowseBySourceList}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:BrowseByStarViewModel">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="{x:Bind icon}"
                            Width="40"
                            Height="40"
                            Margin="10"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind read}"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                TextAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Margin="20, 0, 0, 0"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <AutoSuggestBox Grid.Row="1" 
                    Name="asbBrowseBySource"
                    TextMemberPath="read"    
                    PlaceholderText="{x:Bind ViewModel._TIPS_source_select}"      
                    LostFocus="asbBrowseBySource_LostFocus"                       
                    GotFocus="asbBrowseBySource_GotFocus"
                    TextChanged="asbBrowseBySource_TextChanged">
        <AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="response:ExploreApiResponseItem">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind read}"
                           Margin="5"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
    </AutoSuggestBox>

    <ComboBox x:Name="BrowseBySourceComboBox"  
                LostFocus="BrowseBySourceComboBox_LostFocus"
                SelectionChanged="BrowseBySourceComboBox_SelectionChanged"
                Grid.Row="2"                                          
                PlaceholderText="{x:Bind ViewModel._TIPS_source_select}"      
                IsTextSearchEnabled="True"                                      
                Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind BrowseBySourceComboBoxList, Mode=OneWay}">

        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="response:ExploreApiResponseItem">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind read}"
                            Margin="5"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

The problem is that as soon as I open the `ContentDialog`, My `AutosuggestBox` gets focused automatically. And because I am setting the `IsSuggestionListOpen = True` inside the `GotFocus` event of the AutosuggestBox, the suggestion list opens up immediately after the content dialog is opened. I want to stop this and open the SuggestionList only after the user clicks/taps on the `AutosuggestBOx`

And to add to this question, when the AutosuggestBox is already focused and I click somewhere outside, it doesn't lose it's focus.

Comment: Try to focus on something else in the `Loaded` event of the `ContentDialog`. For example `yourElement.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);`

Comment: tried that, but `AutosuggestBox.GotFocus` is fired after `ContentDialog.Opened`

Comment: That's probably because `ContentDialog` is not focusable so it focuses the first focusable child. Try focusing the `ComboBox`.

Comment: typo there, edited my comment, In my `ContentDialog.Opened` event  I am setting focus away from the `AutosuggestBox`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try switching the order between the `AutoSuggestBox` and your `ListView`, then set the `ListView`'s `IsTapStop` to `True`.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="3" IsTabStop="True" ... />
<AutoSuggestBox Grid.Row="1" ... />
```

---

### Update

There's a `Grid` inside `ContentDialog`'s default style that has a default `Padding` (i.e. `ContentDialogPadding`) and it somehow prevents `LostFocus` from happening.

You can fix this by removing this `Padding` and manually spacing the elements within.

```
<Style TargetType="ContentDialog">
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
            Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
            Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight"
            Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMaxHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth"
            Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMaxWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentDialog">
                <Border x:Name="Container">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonsVisibilityStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="AllVisible" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="NoneVisible">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="PrimaryButton.Visibility"
                                            Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.Visibility"
                                            Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter Target="CloseButton.Visibility"
                                            Value="Collapsed" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PrimaryVisible">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="PrimaryButton.(Grid.Column)"
                                            Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Target="PrimaryButton.(Grid.ColumnSpan)"
                                            Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Target="PrimaryButton.Margin"
                                            Value="2,0,0,0" />
                                    <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.Visibility"
                                            Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter Target="CloseButton.Visibility"
                                            Value="Collapsed" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SecondaryVisible">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.(Grid.Column)"
                                            Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.(Grid.ColumnSpan)"
                                            Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.Margin"
                                            Value="2,0,0,0" />
                                    <Setter Target="PrimaryButton.Visibility"
                                            Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter Target="CloseButton.Visibility"
                                            Value="Collapsed" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CloseVisible">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="CloseButton.(Grid.Column)"
                                            Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Target="CloseButton.(Grid.ColumnSpan)"
                                            Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Target="CloseButton.Margin"
                                            Value="2,0,0,0" />
                                    <Setter Target="PrimaryButton.Visibility"
                                            Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.Visibility"
                                            Value="Collapsed" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PrimaryAndSecondaryVisible">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="PrimaryButton.(Grid.ColumnSpan)"
                                            Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.(Grid.Column)"
                                            Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.(Grid.ColumnSpan)"
                                            Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.Margin"
                                            Value="2,0,0,0" />
                                    <Setter Target="CloseButton.Visibility"
                                            Value="Collapsed" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PrimaryAndCloseVisible">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="PrimaryButton.(Grid.ColumnSpan)"
                                            Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Target="CloseButton.(Grid.Column)"
                                            Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Target="CloseButton.(Grid.ColumnSpan)"
                                            Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Target="CloseButton.Margin"
                                            Value="2,0,0,0" />
                                    <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.Visibility"
                                            Value="Collapsed" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SecondaryAndCloseVisible">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.(Grid.Column)"
                                            Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.(Grid.ColumnSpan)"
                                            Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.Margin"
                                            Value="0,0,2,0" />
                                    <Setter Target="CloseButton.(Grid.Column)"
                                            Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Target="CloseButton.(Grid.ColumnSpan)"
                                            Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Target="CloseButton.Margin"
                                            Value="2,0,0,0" />
                                    <Setter Target="PrimaryButton.Visibility"
                                            Value="Collapsed" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DefaultButtonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="NoDefaultButton" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PrimaryAsDefaultButton">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="PrimaryButton.Style"
                                            Value="{StaticResource AccentButtonStyle}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SecondaryAsDefaultButton">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="SecondaryButton.Style"
                                            Value="{StaticResource AccentButtonStyle}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CloseAsDefaultButton">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="CloseButton.Style"
                                            Value="{StaticResource AccentButtonStyle}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}"
                                BorderThickness="{ThemeResource ContentDialogBorderWidth}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}"
                                MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxHeight}"
                                MinWidth="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMinWidth}"
                                MinHeight="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMinHeight}">
                            <Grid x:Name="DialogSpace"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentScrollViewer"
                                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                              ZoomMode="Disabled"
                                              Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogContentScrollViewerMargin}"
                                              IsTabStop="False">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <ContentControl x:Name="Title"
                                                        Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogTitleMargin}"
                                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}"
                                                        FontSize="20"
                                                        FontFamily="XamlAutoFontFamily"
                                                        FontWeight="Normal"
                                                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                        IsTabStop="False">
                                            <ContentControl.Template>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                                      MaxLines="2"
                                                                      TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                                      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </ContentControl.Template>
                                        </ContentControl>
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"
                                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                          FontSize="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"
                                                          FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"
                                                          Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogContentMargin}"
                                                          Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                                          Grid.Row="1"
                                                          TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                                <Grid x:Name="CommandSpace"
                                      Margin="24,0,24,24"
                                      Grid.Row="1"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                      XYFocusKeyboardNavigation="Enabled">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Button x:Name="PrimaryButton"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding PrimaryButtonText}"
                                            IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsPrimaryButtonEnabled}"
                                            Style="{TemplateBinding PrimaryButtonStyle}"
                                            ElementSoundMode="FocusOnly"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            Margin="0,0,2,0"
                                            Grid.Column="0" />
                                    <Button x:Name="SecondaryButton"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding SecondaryButtonText}"
                                            IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsSecondaryButtonEnabled}"
                                            Style="{TemplateBinding SecondaryButtonStyle}"
                                            ElementSoundMode="FocusOnly"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            Margin="2,0,2,0"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                                    <Button x:Name="CloseButton"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding CloseButtonText}"
                                            Style="{TemplateBinding CloseButtonStyle}"
                                            ElementSoundMode="FocusOnly"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            Margin="2,0,0,0"
                                            Grid.Column="3" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The code above is mostly from the default style, except two changes I made -

1. I removed the `Padding` on `DialogSpace`.
2. I gave `CommandSpace` a `Margin` of `24,0,24,24`.

Lastly, I added a default `Padding` of `24,18,24,0` to your **top** level `Grid` inside the `ContentDialog`.

---

### Update 2

If you want to dismiss the `AutoSuggestBox`'s `Popup`, you will have to do it manually. Inside its `GotFocus` handler, use `VisualTreeHelper` to locate the background rectangle, and hook up with its `Tapped` event, so whenever it's tapped, you just manually set `IsSuggestionListOpen` to `false`. You will also have to set the focus onto another control.

```
var box = (AutoSuggestBox)sender;
box.IsSuggestionListOpen = true;

var popups = VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups(Window.Current);
foreach (var popup in popups)
{
    if (popup.Child is Rectangle bg)
    {
        bg.Tapped += Bg_Tapped;

        void Bg_Tapped(object s, TappedRoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            bg.Tapped -= Bg_Tapped;

            box.IsSuggestionListOpen = false;
            BrowseBySourceTopResultsListView.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry I didn't mention it but I was implementing AutosuggestBox to replace that ComboBox

Comment: Works for the first part, Now how can I make the AutosuggestBox lose focus ?

Comment: So when you tap outside of it, it doesn't lose focus automatically?

Comment: No. In case of ComboBox also neither `Combobox.LostFocus` nor `ContentDialog.GotFocus` events are fired but still the `ComboBox` list closes. Here with `AutosuggestBox` neither of the two events fire ( But I want the suggestion pane to close )

Comment: You typically don't need to handle lost focus at all. Can you show more of your xaml? If you are saying clicking outside of the box doesn't close the pane automatically, there could be something else wrong in your code.

Comment: I've updated my question. This is everything I have inside my contentdialog. And this content dialog code is placed inside `SplitView.Content` of my MainPage. I am not handling any lostfocus events, I just put it there to see if it is actually getting or losing focus

Comment: doesn't work. The only way it loses focus is when I click on the `Border` that is inside my contentdialog or when I click one of the buttons of contentdialog. Clicking the ListViewItem also does this but I don't want the listvieewitem to get selected

Comment: Yeah it's an annoying issue, I just noticed, and see my fix in the updated answer.

Comment: So it will work only when user taps in the padded area, right ?

Comment: yes I did, the problem I that you have to be very precise with mouse pointer

Comment: Where else do you want to click?

Comment: Any other control inside or outside the `ContentDialog`? like combobox behaves.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149112/discussion-between-ravi-kumar-and-justin-xl).

Comment: @DanyKhalife `TabIndex` doesn't stop the control from getting focus.

Comment: @JustinXL that's exactly my point.. One should not prevent a control from getting focus, or attempt to 'fix' it in a hacky way. If I understood correctly, the issue could be resolved simply by setting the correct TabIndex such that his control doesn't get priority.

Comment: @DanyKhalife no, changing the ordering of elements is not a hacky way. It doesn't require someone to look through all the indexes to figure out what tab sequence an element has. Also, the issue the OP was facing was a lot more than just setting the focus.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a my code ... yes it's dirty but works :) 
This handler is attached to the 'Opend' event of the content dialog.

```
    private async void manageBoardsDialog_Opened(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogOpenedEventArgs args)
    {
        // at first, disable the autosuggest control
        autoSuggestBox.IsEnabled = false;
        // do some async task
        // Set focus to another control 
        itemGridView.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
        // re-enable it
        autoSuggestBox.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

UWP sets focus on first Editable Control on Visual Tree. So you can add a Editable control, Make sure it is not visible on UI even though it is still on UI( Do not enable/disable `Visibility`) and then set the focus to that control on Load Manually to make sure it receives the focus.

Here's what i did before when i had the same issue.

Add below in your `ContentDialog`

```
<TextBox x:Name="FocusedTextBox" Width="0" Height="0" Opacity="0" Margin="-5000,0,0,0" />
```

Now in your `Loaded` Just say

```
FocusedTextBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

Comment: this solves the initial problem, now how to make AutosuggestBox lose it's focus by clicking anywhere outside.

Comment: @ravikumar That should also work automatically. Any control that GotFocus, when clicked outside will lose focus automatically.

Comment: the whole thing is inside a `ContentDialog` and you probably mean to say that by clicking outside, the `ContentDialog` will get focus and AutosuggestBox will lose focus, but this doesn't happen

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to call Focus(). If you debug the code, you will notice that focus will still be jumping to the passwordbox initially. Say Narrator is On for instance (or any screen reader), it may struggle in picking up the change of focus quickly and end up reading the wrong thing, or worse, reading both the password box accessible text & the TextBox you actually want to get focus.. A good solution is one that hints Windows into knowing which elements have priority over others with respect to focus. See Control.TabIndex :)